# Topic/ subject + controlling idea

Tags: subjects

Can someone help me identify the subject + the controlling idea of this sentence.

If you’ve ever dreamed of exploring Andalucia, Catalonia, or Mallorca, we invite you to explore Spain on a bike tour with us.

Thank you,

Comment: [This RIT article](https://www.rit.edu/ntid/sea/processes/paragraph/process/sentence#:~:text=The%20controlling%20idea%20is%20the,Running%20provides%20many%20healthful%20benefits.) 'defines' _topic_ and _controlling idea_ (locally; they're stipulative definitions, as far as I can see) but claims that in the 'topic sentence' _The basics of using an SLR camera can be mastered with considerable practice._ the 'topic' is _an SLR camera_. While the subject, well-defined from established English grammar, is _The basics of using an SLR camera_.

Comment: Topic is the subject and the controlling idea is what can be said about the subject.

Comment: [YourDictionary.com](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-topic-sentences.html) provides an example: << Topic Sentence: _Fortune hunters encounter many difficulties when exploring a shipwreck._
The topic is "exploring a shipwreck" and the controlling idea is "many difficulties." >> The logic here is probably that the whole chapter or above is about fortune hunters; this paragraph focuses on _wreck diving_ and in particular details _the difficulties involved_. // The snag with OP's example is that this seems article- not just paragraph-introductory.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence is *we*. The topic (what the sentence is about) is exploring Spain on a bike tour. The controlling idea is "Only open to those who really want to visit the three regions mentioned".

Comment: Is there a 'controlling idea'? _Only open to those who really want to visit the three regions mentioned?_

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll add that to my answer. I figured answering 2/3 of the questions might be sufficient. :)

Comment: I would say the controlling idea was _explore Spain on a bike tour with us._ Clearly that's the one the authors want the readers to pay most attention to.

Comment: Thank you John. However what is the main idea ? / topic ? if the controlling idea is explore Spain on a bike tour with us ?